# Generic Constraints vs. Inheritance

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, mocking

I'm trying to write some code to help unit test WCF services. These services are accessed through a facade class that creates the proxy instance, then calls the proxy method and returns the result; for each proxy method. I'd like to be able to replace the current creation code with something that either creates the real service or a fake one.

I couldn't get that to work. I boiled it down to the following:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ExpressionTrees
{
    public interface IMyContract
    {
        void Method();
    }

    public class MyClient : ClientBase<IMyContract>, IMyContract
    {
        public MyClient()
        {
        }

        public MyClient(string endpointConfigurationName)
            : base(endpointConfigurationName)
        {
        }

        public void Method()
        {
            Channel.Method();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public TClient MakeClient<TClient>()
            where TClient : ClientBase<IMyContract>, IMyContract, new()
        {
            return new MyClient("config");

            // Error:
            // Cannot convert expression of type 'ExpressionTrees.ServiceClient' to return type 'TClient'
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it that, even though the `MyClient` class derives from `ClientBase<IMyContract>` and implements `IMyContract`, that I can't return a `MyClient` instance from a method meant to return a `TClient`? `TClient` specifies a type constraint I had thought meant the same thing.

---

My goal was to call code like this:

```
    public void CallClient<TClient>()
        where TClient : ClientBase<IMyContract>, IMyContract
    {
        TClient client = null;
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            client = MakeClient<TClient>();
            client.Method();
            client.Close();
            success = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success && client != null)
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

But instead of always calling `MakeClient<TClient>`, I wanted to be able to have a unit test inject a mock object. Since the code above depends both on `ClientBase<IMyContract>`, `IMyContract`, it seems I was trying to "synthesize" a generic class that would satisfy that constraint.

In retrospect, this wouldn't make sense. As an example, the `ClientBase<IMyContract>` would expect to be instantiated in such a way that a `Channel` object would be constructed that it could then delegate the `Close` method to.

I've wound up punting on having the exact same code run both for the real and for the fake services. I'm now injecting an `IMyService`, and either calling `IMyService.Method` or `client.Method` depending on whether my injected property is null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically your code boils down to:

```
    public static T MakeFruit<T>() where T : Fruit 
    { 
        return new Apple(); 
    }
```

This always returns an apple, even if you call `MakeFruit<Banana>()`.  But `MakeFruit<Banana>()` is required to return a banana, not an apple.

The meaning of the generic type constraint is that the type argument provided by the caller must match the constraint. So in my example, you can say `MakeFruit<Banana>()` but not `MakeFruit<Tiger>()` because Tiger does not match the constraint that T must be convertible to Fruit. I think you believe that the constraint means something else; I'm not sure what that is.

Think about it like this.  A formal parameter has a formal parameter type. The formal parameter type restricts the type of the expression that is used as an argument.  So when you say:

```
void M(Fruit x)
```

you are saying "the argument passed for formal parameter x in M must be convertible to Fruit".

Generic type parameter constraints are exactly the same; they are restrictions on what type arguments may be passed for the generic type parameters. When you say "where T : Fruit", that is just the same as saying (Fruit x) in the formal parameter list. T has got to be a type that goes to Fruit, just as the argument for x has got to be an argument that goes to Fruit.

Why do you even want to have a generic method in the first place? I don't understand what exactly you're trying to model with this method or why you want it to be generic.

Comment: Eric, I'll take the example one step deeper so it's clear what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You are restricting the TClient in the `MakeClient<TClient>()` portion of the call, not the return type.

The return type has to match the type of the generic parameter, but picture this:

```
public class MyOtherClient : ClientBase<IMyContract>, IMyContract
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Channel.Method();
    }
}
```

That's also a valid return by calling `MakeClient<MyOtherClient>`, which `MyClient` is not convertable to, since it should return a type of `MyOtherClient`.

Note that changing the return to:

```
return new MyClient() as TClient;
```

would probably get it past the compiler, but be null in my scenario above at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue.

```
static T Make<T>() where T : IConvertible
{
    var s = "";
    return (T)(Object)s;        
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I really need a parameterized constructor. I updated my question to show that.